# ListView with non-uniform ListItems

Tags: android

I have to implement a `ListView` or `GridView` where every item will have non-uniform height/width. Also a particular item could span multiple columns. A `GridView` is perhaps a better candidate, but again each row has a different schematic. The attached image best describes what I want to achieve.

[image: Non Uniform ListView]

I am looking for ideas on how best to implement this. I am not looking for code samples, but just some guidelines.

Right now, I'm thinking of implementing a custom `ListAdapter` where each row is laid out in the scheme I want. Of course then I'd have to do some tricks to map list indexes to actually items in array of items (if I use and array adapter). For example, in the mockup below, the penguins will have an index of 1 in my array, but 0 in the `ListView`.

Comment: See if either of these can be helpful: https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary or https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

Comment: use StaggeredGridView as suggested by @IceMAN

Answer (score 0):

in these kind of structure you should use a layout in xml and add dynamic view in that layout from java file.

Answer (score 0):

May be a relative Layout with ImageViews is good. It may get a bit messy for the .xml though! This seems quite interesting. Do keep us updated on which of the solutions you finally chose.

Thanks!